# ViewController - Fullscreen

Tags: ios, swift

The second ViewController has this space on top and it almost shows up as a dismissable-popup on the phone. How to make is full screen (remove the space pointed with the Orange arrow)?

[image]

Comment: Is it happening on a Simulator or a real device?

Comment: Happening in Both simulator and real device

Comment: is related to Xcode 11 and iOS 13 update?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is an iOS 13 change. Users will start to expect to be able to swipe away modals so it might be worth looking into supporting that.

If you're really set on using the old presentation style you can do so by setting the modalPresentationStyle of the presented viewController either before presenting:

```
vc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
```

or override it in the view controller itself:

```
override var modalPresentationStyle: UIModalPresentationStyle {
    get { .fullScreen }
    set { assertionFailure("Shouldnt change that ") }
}
```

or set in in the storyboard segue:

[image: storyboard segue example]

Comment: This was helpful! I was setting each VC's `.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen` in their individual init/viewDidLoad functions, but that was not working. What worked was setting the `.modalPresentationStyle` programmatically on the presented VC instance before presenting.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same issue. Override the prepare for segue in your UIViewController implementation. Setting the navigationController.modalPresentationStyle to .fullScreen

```
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
  // Get the presented navigationController and the view controller it contains
  let navigationController = segue.destination
    navigationController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
}
```